# How to make a bool loop within console c++?

Tags: c++, console

I am trying to do a simple game within console with c++.
Everything went perfect, but I cant just get the bool "fishing" looped. It just returns 0 after the first session of "fishing".
Here's my code

```
 fishing = false;
              
            if (fishing == false) {
                system("cls");
                cout << "Do you wish to fish again?" << endl;
                cout << "Current Amount of fish: ";
                cout << fish << endl;
                cin >> hellyea;
                if (hellyea == 1)
                    fishing = true;
            }

            while (fishing == true) {

                // the "waiting to catch a fish" part


                // randomly selecting type of fishes
                system("cls");
                srand(time(NULL));
                auto fishtype = rand() % 3;

                if (fishtype == 0) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "You just got an: " << "Common Carp!" << endl;
                    fish++;
                    cout << "Your Fish Amount: ";
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    cout << fish << endl;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
                    Sleep(2000);

                }
                if (fishtype == 1) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Argh! You just found: " << "A bag Of Trash!" << endl;
                    cout << "You lose 1 fish :(" << endl;
                    fish = fish - 1;
                    if (fish == -1)
                        fish++;
                    cout << "Your Fish Amount: ";
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    cout << fish << endl;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
                    Sleep(2000);
                }
                if (fishtype == 2) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "You just got an: " << "Gold Fish! Congrats!";
                    fish++;
                    cout << "Your Fish Amount: ";
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    cout << fish << endl;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
                    Sleep(2000);
                }
                fishing = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you told it to:

```
fishing = false;
```

Right at the end of the loop.

Naturally, checking `fishing == true` right after that will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep fishing after catching a fish
you will need to put the "do you want to fish again?"
inside a separate for/while loop so that the question
is asked again after catching a fish.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your while loop you make `fishing = false` and loop ends because `fishing == true` return 0

```
fishing = false;

            if (fishing == false) {
                system("cls");
                cout << "Do you wish to fish again?" << endl;
                cout << "Current Amount of fish: ";
                cout << fish << endl;
                cin >> hellyea;
                if (hellyea == 1)
                    fishing = true;
            }

            while (fishing == true) {

                // the "waiting to catch a fish" part


                // randomly selecting type of fishes
                system("cls");
                srand(time(NULL));
                auto iSecret = rand() % 3;

                if (iSecret == 0) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "You just got an: " << "Common Carp!" << endl;
                    fish++;
                    cout << "Your Fish Amount: ";
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    cout << fish << endl;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
                    Sleep(2000);

                }
                if (iSecret == 1) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Argh! You just found: " << "A bag Of Trash!" << endl;
                    cout << "You lose 1 fish :(" << endl;
                    fish = fish - 1;
                    if (fish == -1)
                        fish++;
                    cout << "Your Fish Amount: ";
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    cout << fish << endl;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
                    Sleep(2000);
                }
                if (iSecret == 2) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "You just got an: " << "Gold Fish! Congrats!";
                    fish++;
                    cout << "Your Fish Amount: ";
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    cout << fish << endl;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
                    Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You don't need to set a variable to `true` when it's `true` already.

Comment: Why on earth did you rename `fishtype`, which is a perfectly descriptive variable name, to `iSecret`, which sounds like a bad iPhone app and tells you nothing?

Comment: You can open your eyes and check that actually Stephan renamed that variable. I never change variable names to some what I want if they already exist.